Git tag not found in Visual Studio 2022
First, I have carefully followed the instructions in remote tag not shown in local and I have already run git fetch --tags. Not solved. I am in VS2022 17.9.6.
Here is my problem: There is a tag for my company's git develop (that's our main branch) source named 24.4.33. I know it exists for 2 reasons:

I can see it in a browser here: https://dev.azure.com/myCo/MyCo/_git/MyRepo?version=GT24.4.33
When I run git tag from cmd line, a long list of tags are displayed, and 24.4.33 is one of them.

Yet when I try to find the tag in VS2022 git, it doesn't display:

You can see that it found 2 instances of 24.4.33 in the commit comments, but no tag displays over on the right side, where it would display if found.
I have done a pull several times, so I know I have latest. What can I do to be able to see that tag in my VS2022 git history?
